# How can you tell if a js class method is static or not?

Tags: javascript, class, reflection

E.g. in javascript, how can we tell the difference between:

```
class Foo { 
   bar() {
   }
}
```

and

```
class Foo { 
   static bar() {
   }
}
```

Especially if we allow inheritance, so `Foo` might extend `Fo`, which might also define a method with the same name.

Context: I'm writing a reflection utility, that has to work with other people's code, and should list the static vs instance methods of a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself. These are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects.
So you can use `<class name>.hasOwnProperty("FUNCTION NAME")` to check it. It will return `True` if the method is `static` and false if not

*UPDATE*

**Example**

```
typeof(Foo.bar) === 'function';  //true
```

Answer (score 2):

If a method is static, it will appear as a property of the constructor:

```
typeof(Foo.bar) === 'function';  //true
```

If a method is non-static, it will appear only on the class prototype:

```
typeof(Foo.prototype.bar) === 'function';  //true
typeof(Foo.bar) === 'function';            //false
```

With inheritance, you'd have to do some sort of recursion, but it's tricky to get inheritance chains neatly with current syntax.